# Redis socket permissions caught between /var/run and http

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, systemd, redis

I'd like my PHP web application (run as user `apache`) to connect to redis via a UNIX socket. So I thought of running redis as user `apache` as well and the socket permissions can be 0700 owned by `apache`. But I also want the socket in `/var/run`, which is owned by `root` and not writable by `apache`.

So if I run redis as `root`, my PHP app cannot connect unless I open the socket permissions, which I'd rather not do if I can avoid it.

How do I square this circle? (Redis is managed by systemd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually IPC sockets don't live in `/run/` directly, but rather in a subdirectory owned by the daemon – such as under `/run/redis/`.

```
drwxr-xr-x 37 root  root  920 Jun  1 08:14 /run/
drwxr-xr-x  2 redis redis  40 Jun  1 08:14 /run/redis/
srw-rw-rw-  1 redis redis   0 Jun  1 08:14 /run/redis/socket=
```

The directory can be automaticaly pre-created with the correct permissions on boot (by a [tmpfiles.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html#) configuration in all systemd versions), or upon starting the service (by the [RuntimeDirectory=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#RuntimeDirectory=) parameter in your service in systemd ≥v211). Very likely that your distribution has already done so.

Note that it would be more secure to run the daemons under separate UIDs, but make the socket *group*-accessible by one of the groups that `apache` is member of. This will allow IPC connections as intended, but will still prevent Apache from messing around with the Redis daemon itself.